# How to create an infinite stream with Java 8

Tags: java, java-8

Is there a easy way to create a infinity stream using [java-8](/questions/tagged/java-8) without external libraries?

For example in Scala:

```
Iterator.iterate(0)(_ + 2)
```

Answer (score 107, accepted):

Yes, there is an **easy** way:

```
IntStream.iterate(0, i -> i + 2);
```

With as usecase:

```
IntStream.iterate(0, i -> i + 2)
         .limit(100)
         .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Which prints out 0 to 198 increasing in steps of 2.

The generic method is:

```
Stream.iterate(T seed, UnaryOperator<T> f);
```

The latter may be more uncommon in usage.

Comment: +1, but it's worth mentioning that `IntStream.generate` can be used when `IntStream.iterate` doesn't fit, e.g. the Fibonacci sequence.

Comment: how `IntStream.iterate` doesn't fit for `Fibnoacci`?

Comment: @AsifMushtaq Can you supply how you would have a stream of Fibonacci numbers with `IntStream.iterate` ?

Answer (score 7):

Here is an example:

```
PrimitiveIterator.OfInt it = new PrimitiveIterator.OfInt() {
    private int value = 0;

    @Override
    public int nextInt() {
        return value++;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasNext() {
        return true;
    }
};

Spliterator.OfInt spliterator = Spliterators.spliteratorUnknownSize(it,
    Spliterator.DISTINCT | Spliterator.IMMUTABLE |
    Spliterator.ORDERED | Spliterator.SORTED);

IntStream stream = StreamSupport.intStream(spliterator, false);
```

It's a bit verbose, as you see. To print the first 10 elements of this stream:

```
stream.limit(10).forEach(System.out::println);
```

You can ofcourse also transform the elements, like you do in your Scala example:

```
IntStream plusTwoStream = stream.map(n -> n + 2);
```

Note that there are built-in infinite streams such as `java.util.Random.ints()` which gives you an infinite stream of random integers.

Comment: Given your `PrimitiveIterator.OfInt it`, a simple `IntStream.generate(it::next)` would work as well. So it even doesn’t have to be an iterator at all, e.g. `IntStream.generate(new AtomicInteger()::incrementAndGet)` will provide such a natural number sequence too.

Comment: Yes, obviously my solution is much more verbose than necessary and there are multiple ways to do it.

Comment: Didn't know `java.util.Random.ints()`, +1

Answer (score 4):

There is another possible solution in **Java 8**:

```
AtomicInteger adder = new AtomicInteger();
IntStream stream = IntStream.generate(() -> adder.getAndAdd(2));
```

Important: an order of numbers is preserved only if the stream is sequential.

---

It's also worth noting that a new version of the [`IntStream.iterate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#iterate-int-java.util.function.IntPredicate-java.util.function.IntUnaryOperator-) has been added since **Java 9**:

```
static IntStream iterate​(int seed,
                         IntPredicate hasNext,
                         IntUnaryOperator next);
```

- *seed -* the initial element;
- *hasNext -* a predicate to apply to elements to determine when the stream must terminate;
- *next -* a function to be applied to the previous element to produce a new element.

Examples:

```
IntStream stream = IntStream.iterate(0, i -> i >= 0, i -> i + 2);

IntStream.iterate(0, i -> i < 10, i -> i + 2).forEach(System.out::println);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can build your own InfiniteStream by implementing stream and consumer and compose both and may will need queue to queueing your data as :

```
public class InfiniteStream<T> implements Consumer<T>, Stream<T> {
private final Stream<T> stream;
private final Queueing q;
...
public InfiniteStream(int length) {
    this.q = new Queueing(this.length);
    this.stream = Stream.generate(q);
    ...
}
    //implement stream methods
    //implement accept
}
```

check full code here
https://gist.github.com/bassemZohdy/e5fdd56de44cea3cd8ff